# how to pass angular scope parameter to highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Hi I am really struggling with this problem and it would be awesome if anyone could help me with it.

I am trying to send the angular "scope" object to the highcharts click event so that I can call the parent controller's method, but every method I try gets a compile error.

Here is what I have in the highcharts options. I am trying to make the $scope parameter not have a compile issue.  The compile error is "cannot find symbol scope".

```
plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    var url = this.series.options.url;
                                    if (!this.series.options.clickable) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    if (this.series.options.url == "") {
                                        $scope.vm.ParentController.generateDrilldown(this.series.options.name, this.x - 1);
                                    } else {
                                        window.open(this.series.options.url);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
}
```

I tried sending the $scope object through the seriesData and then just trying to call "this.series.options.scope" but that didnt work. I made a field for scope in my overall class but that didnt work.  I dont know what else to try.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: It's not a good idea to pass around scope.  Why not have all the chart options on `$scope` and watch for changes in the chartOptions object and react accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you explain a little more about what you mean? Is it possible to watch for  when a user clicks on the highchart series? (i.e. when the plotoptions.series.events.click function is invoked). SOrry I am kind of new to angular..

Comment: Your best bet is to check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Cp73s/